# Is there an env var 'SSH_PWD', and how do I use it to restore my last 'pwd' prior to logout?

Tags: debian, ssh, environment-variables, sshd, .bash-logout

The lab has several "Raspberry Pi" machines which run a *Debian-flavor* OS. They are used for specific purposes - which is to say that after I make an SSH connection, I `cd` to the folder where "my stuff" is. For example, on the one I'm connected to at present, I spend much of my time in the folder `~/pico/ina260_i2c/build`.

When I login to this machine via SSH, I would like to be taken to the folder I was in just before I logged out; i.e. normally to `~/pico/ina260_i2c/build`. Of course that's not **always** the case, which is why I want to be taken to the *folder I was in just before I logged out*.

My question is, **"How do I configure my system(s) to make that happen?"**

Here's what I've tried:

1. I found what I thought was a *perfect* answer to my question [here](https://superuser.com/a/46888/907399)... *perfect* except that it doesn't work! I knew there was at least one thing wrong with it (`ssh` is in `/usr/bin/ssh` instead of `/bin/ssh`), and fixed that. Other than that, it *seems to me* the failure here is that the `SSH_PWD` environment variable (derived from `PWD`) does not persist across `SSH` logins.

   This *seemed* promising, but doesn't work:

   ```bash
   $ sudo echo "SendEnv SSH_PWD" >> /etc/ssh_config && sudo echo "AcceptEnv SSH_PWD" >> /etc/sshd_config
   # edit ~/.profile to add the following: 
   alias ssh='env SSH_PWD="$PWD" /usr/bin/ssh'
   if [ -n "$SSH_PWD" ]; then   # i.e. -n => non-zero string; 
   cd "$SSH_PWD"
   unset SSH_PWD
   fi
   ```

   I also tried setting `PermitUserEnvironment yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
2. Other searches for an answer turned up a few things that *seemed* promising, but I [don't know PAM at all](https://serverfault.com/a/388831/515728) so was nervous about even trying that solution.

Comment: Maybe you could use `screen` or `tmux`, then you'd be able to keep your shell session(s) running on the remote machine and reattach it(them) at will.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks - That's a **good** suggestion for most people, but I have to `reboot` fairly regularly - and frankly have never become *comfortable* w/ multiplexers (even tried [byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) briefly).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your login shell is bash on these systems, you can accomplish this completely on the remote side without needing to edit any system configuration. Edit `~/.bash_logout` (creating it if doesn't exist), and add:

```bash
# Save current directory to a file on logout
printf '%s\0' "$PWD" > ~/.my_previous_session_pwd
```

And in your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile`, whichever exists, in that order), add:

```bash
# If the previous session's working directory was saved to file, switch to it
if
  [ -r ~/.my_previous_session_pwd ] &&
    IFS= read -rd '' old_dir < ~/.my_previous_session_pwd &&
    [ -d "$old_dir" ]
then
  cd -- "$old_dir"
fi
```